# Dynamically updating graph(moving line graph) based on API in Angular/ChartJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, charts, angular6

I'm trying to implement a moving line graph(dynamically updating graph) based on API calls,
but i'm getting an error.

[image]

graph's x-axis should be time and y-axis should be the stock_price.I use Chart.js forgraphs and Angular6.

**app component**

```
export class AppComponent {
   chart = [];


 ngOnInit(){
   this._helper.helperHelp()
   .subscribe(res => {
    //  console.log(res);
    let times = [];
   console.log(res);
    let stock_price = res['stock_price'].map(res=>res.stock_price); 
    let timeloop = res['time'].map(res =>res.time);
    //console.log(time);
    timeloop.forEach((res) => {
      times.push(times);
    });





    this.chart = new Chart('canvas',{
      type: 'line',
      data : {
        labels : times,
        datasets: [
          {
            data:stock_price,
            borderColor: '#3cba9f',
            fill: false
          }
        ]
      },

     options:{
       legend:{
         display: false
       },
       scales: {
         xAxis:[{
           display:true
         }],
         yAxis:[{
           display:true
         }]
       }
     }


    })
   })
  //  console.log(this.timeSetter());
 }



 constructor(private _helper:HelperService){
  setInterval(()=>{
    this.ngOnInit(); },4000); 
  }
```

This is what i receive from the json file

```
 {
stock_price: 58,
time: "06:06:00am"
}
```

and next

```
 {
stock_price: 59,
time: "06:06:04am"
}
```

like that from the API.

I think the problem is the way how i use map() function, but i still can't understand how to use it properly. I referred this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTzi5DS7On4) when making this.

Comment: res is an object, res['stock_price'] gives you a number and numbers don't have map methods.

Comment: so do i have to convert it to a string? @PavanBahuguni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` operater must be called on an array. In the console error you've posted, the value for `res` is a single object.

Since you only get one value back you can either:

1. Wrap the response in an array:

   `[{
      stock_price: 59,
      time: "06:06:04am"
   }]`
2. Refactor the code so that you don't need to use map. I'm thinking something like this may work.

   `let stock_price = res['stock_price'].stock_price;`

Comment: i think without map function, i won't be able to implement chartjs :/

Comment: @AVI then just wrap it in an array `[ res['stock_price'].stock_price ]` and try

Comment: now error has gone :) +1 , but chart didn't appear :(

Comment: Great. Unfortunately, the chart not appearing could be caused by many factors, if you create an example on https://stackblitz.com I can take a look.

Comment: elakiri :D i'll try

Comment: but i'm having difficulties when adding some of the npm packages like, @angular/common/http :/\

Comment: Oh okay, just get much of the code as possible and post the stackblitz. That would help.

Comment: Ela :D. Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tdjze?file=src/app/app.component.ts 

Had to make some changes. Such as removing the service and not calling onInit in an interval (That is not recommended, OnInit should only be called from Angular.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173196/discussion-between-avi-and-nipuna777).